# Set the focus to the editor after a widget is added in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

How can I set the focus to the editor in CKEditor after a widget is added?
I don't want that the widget stays in focus

Answer (score 2):

have you added startupFocus : true to your config file?

Look up: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Set-focus-load

An excerpt from my custom config file looks something like this

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    config.extraPlugins = 'confighelper';
    config.autoGrow_onStartup = true;
    config.autogrow_minheight = 50;
    config.autogrow_maxheight = 200;
    config.contentsLangDirection = 'ui';
    config.startupFocus = true; 

    //more options...
};
```